# ViewPager animation with buttons using PagerTransformer

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I'm trying to do some animation on my ViewPager. On my main View i have a ViewPager and two buttons. what I want to do is when I click on left button then view in viewPager is move to the left (off-screen) and next view fades in and the same way for right button but to right side. (something like Tinder app effect but simplest). I found a nice interface named ViewPager.PageTransformer but i can't figure out how to move view in way that I want.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

This repo has a handful of animations. If what you're looking for isn't present, at least you have a decent start.

https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms

Comment: Don't add link. Link can be vanish !

Comment: What? Why? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see this. It shows a sample having 2 buttons and pages scrolls on click of these.
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Don't add link. Link can be vanish !

Comment: It's something what I'm fooking for, but I can't get how to move view to the right with right button click. (for now I have this effect when i back to previous view. I wish to have this when i get next view )

Comment: on click of right button call pager.setCurrentPage(index of left page). onclick of left button call pager.setCurrentPage(index of right page).

Comment: This will work when I want to step back na viewpager, but what i want is to go forward with diffrent animations of each buttons click.